# String with single quote in graphical calculation view HANA

Tags: hana

We have HANA database with SPS 12 version.

We have graphical calculation view where we have created calculated column with 'if..else' logic. Below is the if else logic used -

```
if("COL1"='A'B','X','Y')
```

I am getting below error-

> Invalid ExpressionSAP DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error: failed to set expression: [6968] Evaluator: syntax error in expression string; expected TK_RPAREN, parsing "if("COL1"='A'[here]B','X','Y')"

[image: ERROR]

I have to check if COL1 has value `A'B`. I am not able to understand how we should handle single quote in Graphical Calculation view.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change language from Column Engine to SQL
[image]

and Expression is:

```
if("COL1"='A''B','X','Y')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can escape a single quote (`'`) by using two single quotes (`''`). Note that this is **not** the double quote character (`"`):

```
if("COL1"='A''B','X','Y')
```